# Cycle through database and every table to find any column that contains phone number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to cycle through every database table and every column to see if it contains a telephone number.
Anything beginning with the text + or 00 or 0.

I have found code/cursors that loop through for column names but they don't search the actual data.
Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Just for further clarification, you are checking for a specific phone number, or a anything (regex) that could be a phone number?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use those cursors in conjunction with a query to find what you want.

Here is a script to search all columns of all tables. I will leave it to you to add in the search all databases

(this is assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or newer. it may work with other systems but it is untested.

```
--fields types to search within
declare table_field_cursor cursor local fast_forward for select sys.tables.name, sys.columns.name from sys.columns inner join sys.tables on (sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id)inner join sys.types on (sys.columns.system_type_id = sys.types.system_type_id)
where sys.tables.type = 'U' and sys.types.name in ('varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar', 'text')

--Stop printing the Rows affected message.
set NOCOUNT ON

--loop through all tables & fields seaching for your string
open table_field_cursor

declare @table_name sysname
declare @field_name sysname

fetch next from table_field_cursor into @table_name, @field_name
while @@fetch_status <> -1
begin
    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> -2
        execute ('
        if EXISTS(select [' + @field_name + '] from [' + @table_name + '] with (nolock) where cast([' + @field_name + '] as nvarchar(3)) like ''+%'' or cast([' + @field_name + '] as nvarchar(3)) like ''0%'')
        begin
        print ''Found in table ' + @table_name + '.' + @field_name + '!''
        select * from [' + @table_name + ']  with (nolock) where cast([' + @field_name + '] as nvarchar(3)) like ''+%'' or cast([' + @field_name + '] as nvarchar(3)) like ''0%''
        end
        ')

    fetch next from table_field_cursor into @table_name, @field_name
end 

close table_field_cursor
deallocate table_field_cursor
```

This will search all tables that have a `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `char`, `nchar`, `text` column and see if it begins with `0` or `+` (we don't need to check for `00` as it is included with the `0` check). If you are able to get rid of the requirement for checking `text` columns you can remove the `nvarchar(3)` castings and possibly speed things up, the casting is done because `text` does not support the `like` query.

To search multiple databases take a look in to [sp_MSForeachdb](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)

Comment: I saw that one but doesn't that check the column name? I want to check the actual data in the column not the name of the column

Comment: No it is actually checking the data, it builds many queries based off the list of the columns. for example if you had a table named `Foo` with two columns named `Bar` and `Baz` it would make the following searches:

Comment: `select * from [Foo] with (nolock) where cast([Bar] as nvarchar(3)) like ''+%'' or cast([Bar] as nvarchar(3)) like ''0%''`

Comment: `select * from [Foo] with (nolock) where cast([Baz] as nvarchar(3)) like ''+%'' or cast([Baz] as nvarchar(3)) like ''0%''`

Comment: That seems to output the entire table. To get the table name, would I just do a select name from sysname?

Comment: Just remove the last Select or click on the `Messages` tab in Management studio. It print's the table names too with the `print ''Found in table ' + @table_name + '.' + @field_name + '!''` line. (Found I forgot to remove a variable. see my updated code)

Comment: I seem to get a whole load of errors with this: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'pt_eyif_fs_out'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'pt_eyif_fs_out'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'pt_eyif_fs_out'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'pt_eyif_fs_out'.

Comment: If you remove that `' + @search + '` does that fix it?

Comment: No, when I double click the error, it highlights this line declare table_field_cursor cursor local fast_forward for select sys.tables.name, sys.columns.name from sys.columns inner join sys.tables on (sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id)inner join sys.types on (sys.columns.system_type_id = sys.types.system_type_id)                 I can still get the tables in Excel after if needed

Comment: That error is not really from that line. You are executing SQL inside your SQL. The real error is from the seccond line passed in to the `execute` commend, so `if EXISTS(select [' + @field_name + '] from [' + @table_name + '] with (nolock) where cast([' + @field_name + '] as nvarchar(3)) like ''+%'' or cast([' + @field_name + '] as nvarchar(3)) like ''0%'')`. You will just have to debug it on your own. I just gave you my code that I have never had a problem with, I don't have time to do tech support for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Oracle Database, in your loop create an sql statement using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, there are many resources on the web, one of them is this one http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm).
using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE you can build sql statements.
hope it helps.
(sorry, i just saw that you're using sql server but there are equivalent things: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/4572e8eb-265c-4e6d-b501-22eef2111caf)